# jQuery - Select only the first element that matches for performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, css-selectors

Is it possible to write a jQuery selector that only selects the first element that matches the criteria and stops there?

I am aware of the not-so-performant `:first` selector and the better `.first()` call, but both appear to select all the elements and then only return the one at position `[0]`.

Let's say I have 100 rows in a table and I need to do something to all of them. They don't have IDs, but rather a `data-guid` attribute with a unique value.

Here's an example with a list:

```
<ol>
    <li data-guid="guid_1">A</li>
    <li data-guid="guid_2">B</li>
    <li data-guid="guid_3">C</li>
    <li data-guid="guid_4">D</li>
</ol>
```

.

```
var data = [
    {guid: "guid_1", new_value: "I"},
    {guid: "guid_2", new_value: "II"},
    {guid: "guid_3", new_value: "III"},
    {guid: "guid_4", new_value: "IV"}
];

var $ol = $('#list');
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    $('li[data-guid="' + data[i].guid + '"]', $ol).text(data[i].new_value);
}
```

Unfortunately, this would run through each element 100 times, making the total DOM iterations reach 10,000. In reality, since GUIDs are unique, it should run through the first element 100 times and the last one only once, making it run 5,050 times.

I guess I'm wondering if there's a way to treat it like an ID selector, where it stops when it finds an element that meets the criteria and then breaks out of the loop.

--

**squint's Solution** (if my interpretation is correct)

```
var data = [
    {guid: "guid_1", new_value: "I"},
    {guid: "guid_2", new_value: "II"},
    {guid: "guid_3", new_value: "III"},
    {guid: "guid_4", new_value: "IV"}
];

// Hashmap in case array is not the same order as list items, look up by GUID
var hashmap = {};
for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; ++i) {
    hashmap[data[i].guid] = data[i];
}

var $ol = $('#list');
$('li[data-guid]', $ol).text(function () {
    var item = hashmap[$(this).attr('attr-guid')];
    return item ? item.new_value : 'N/A';
});
```

Comment: I suppose there's `$(document.querySelector('CSS selector'))`, but I'm not sure it's any more performant, though it's explicitly designed to return only the first match.

Comment: `document.getElementById("list").querySelectorAll('li[data-guid]')` then iterate the result.

Comment: @squint: if you're using `querySelectorAll()`, is it any faster to chain the methods, as in your previous comment, rather than just using `querySelectorAll('#list li[data-guid]')`?

Comment: Probably depends on implementation, but I believe that a right to left selection is typically done, which means all the `li[data-guid]` would be selected first, then each one would need to verify that it's inside the `#list`. If so, then it would be slower.

Comment: @MMiller: As to a more idiomatic yet better performing jQuery solution: `$("#list").find("li[data-guid]").text(function() { return data.new_value; });`. You can put `.slice(0, N)` before `.text()` if you need only the first `N` elements.

Comment: ...overall your example in the question is incomplete, and raises a number of questions, like why are you using the same `.guid` and `.new_value` in the loop? That makes little sense.

Comment: @squint I meant `data[i]`. As for your answer, I understand that I can use `slice`, but the initial call still has to iterate over all the elements in the list when it only needs the first one. After that, slice shouldn't make a difference, because the result from the query is only 1 element.

Comment: @MMiller: Oh you think it does, huh. I don't know why you'd take the approach you're taking. My solutions above get all the elements that have that `data-guid` attribute, so you only have to do the DOM selection once. You can then iterate the collection. But since we don't know anything about the data that has the `guid` numbers, it's hard to give a real solution. Based on the info provided, I'd say you should create a new data object with `guid` numbers as keys so that you can just loop through the entire set, and grab the data based on the value of `data-guid`.

Comment: Oh, I get it! Duh, I should be iterating through the DOM nodes instead of the data itself, assuming there's a 1:1 data piece to DOM node, which there is in my scenario (sorry for not clarifying that, I added sample data). So what you're saying is this (I added it to my question).

Answer (score 1):

this run only data.length times (see console log)

```
    <ol id="list">
     <li data-guid="1">Coffee</li>
     <li data-guid="2">Tea</li>
     <li data-guid="5">Milk</li>
     <li data-guid="6">Water</li>
    </ol> 

    var $ol = $('#list');
    var data = [[1,"Saab"], [2,"Volvo"], [3,"BMW"], [6,"Nissan"]]; 
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
       $ol.find('li[data-guid="' + data[i][0] + '"]').text(data[i][1]);
       console.log(i);
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rLbd7fuc/

Comment: The array only runs `data.length` times, but jQuery traverses through each item in the list `data.length` times, resulting in `data.length` ^ 2 iterations.

Comment: M Miller thanks for clarify. What about this: $('#list li').each(function(){
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        alert( i );
    if( $(this).attr('data-guid')==  data[i][0]){
        $(this).text(data[i][1]);
        alert( $(this).text() );
        break;
        
    }
}  http://jsfiddle.net/rLbd7fuc/1/

Comment: if you need break the iteration on ordened list, return false into loop each. (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can use the `:first` selector to get only fhe first element of the collection, but, quoting the official jQuery documentation:

> Because :first is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :first cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. To achieve the best performance when using :first to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use .filter(":first").

Both the `:first` selector and `.filter()` method don't really improve/boost your code so much.

**If you only want to select the first element, then the best solution is to use `document.querySelector()`**, that stops on the first element and returns it.

So here it is:

```
var $ol = $('#list');
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    $(document.querySelector('li[data-guid="' + data.guid + '"]'), $ol).text(data.new_value);
}
```

Comment: Using `:eq()` that way will provide no performance benefit. It's still just the wrong way to approach the problem. I'd bet that the `:first` is just sugar for `:eq(0)`.